# How to take a specific string from a csv file into a list - python 3.4

Tags: python, csv

I have a csv list with 3 rows but i only want to take the first string from each of these rows and append them to a new list.

```
names = list()
a = open(sf, 'r')
for row in a:
    names.append(row[0])
print (names)
```

The output I get from this is only the first letter of each of the strings. How do I go about it so I get the entire string as they all vary in lengths. Thanks in advance

Comment: Give sample input and expected output and you are reading a csv file using normal reader where as you should use csv reader

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try looking for the comma in the csv:

```
names = list()
a = open(sf, 'r')
for row in a:
    place = row.find(',')
    names.append(row[:place])
print(names)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use csv module to do it.

```
import csv  

names = []
a = open(sf, 'r')

reader = csv.reader(a, delimiter=',')

for row in reader:
    names.append(row[0])

print names
```

Comment: instead of `list()` you could use `[]` it is faster

Comment: @VigneshKalai Thank you for information! Updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Another way is like this:

```
names = []
with open(sf, 'r') as fi:
    for row in fi:
        names.append(row.split(',')[0])

print(names)
```

Here you split the row on delimiter of your csv (here on comma) and append the first element to the names.

If you would rather split on whitespace, you can use `split()` without argument.